# Как проигрывать короткое аудио в UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, аудио

Я получаю звук с микрофона с помощью `AudioGraph`. При работе с аудиографом аудиофреймы достаются каждые 10 мс. Полученные данные я преобразую в 16 битный 16 kHz моно. Плюс добавляю wav-header. И все эти байты я загоняю в `InMemoryRandomAccessStream` и отправляю

```
mediaElement.SetSource(memoryStream.AsRandomAccessStream(), "audio/x-wav");
```

И вот этот звук невозможно слушать, поскольку этот медиаэлемент каждый раз останавливается и запускается, поэтому слышен только шум.
Если я накапливаю данные до 100 мс, то все более-менее, но все равно чувствуется переход. Что мне делать?

**Обновление**

Или же мне надо создавать новый аудиограф и с помощью него воспроизводить звук?